# Android Studio - Lots of "Resource Not Found" Errors, Importing Incorrectly?

Tags: android, android-studio, import, resources, zip

I recently bought an app on Flippa (App Buy/Sell Marketplace) that is similar to Tetris. When I import it into Android Studio, I get lots of "Resource Not Found" Errors. I have looked at lots of other Resource Not Found Error questions, with no luck in resolving my issue. I searched through multiple YouTube videos, which all result in something that isn't my issue, or some foreign guy that I cannot understand. I have Cleaned the project, I have Rebuilt the project, I have Synced the project, I have reopened Android Studio, I invalidated caches/restarted. I have closed and reopened the project. I have restarted my Macbook Air. I have downloaded the .zip and tried getting the app to work on my PC I built that is running Windows 10. Both my PC and Macbook Air have the latest version of Android Studio Installed. I think I installed all of the things I need from the SDK Manager. I know it must be some setting or something I need to change because there is probably 50 - 200 of these errors that pop up. Here is exactly what I do.

1) Download .zip file
2) Extract .zip file
3) Open Android Studio & Click Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, Etc.)
4) Open Unzipped Folder, and Select Source Code. Click Ok.
5) Click "Create Project From Existing Sources". Click Next.
6) Set Project Name & Location to What I Want it Saved As. Click Next.
7) It Shows Lots of Source Files From Various Projects. I have tried both leaving them all selected, and only selecting the ones for the Tetris App.
8) Shows Libraries From Various Projects. Leave Them All Selected and Click Next.
9) Shows Modules From Various Projects. Leave Them All Selected and Click Next.
10) Please Select Project SDK. Default is 1.8 (Which I Leave Chosen Every Time). Options are 1.8, Android API 18 Platform, Android API 19 Platform, Android API 20 Platform, Android API 22 Platform, Android API 23 Platform, Android API 25 Platform.
11) Leave Detected Frameworks Selected, then Click Finish.

Maybe I'm just importing the project wrong? Could someone please give me a step by step on how to get from .zip file to being able to edit & run the app on Android Studio? Thanks!!

Comment: kindly check you have imported properly all the drawable (i.e res folder is having all this used in layout files)

Comment: If I import the source code folder for the app, it contains the res folder, which contains drawable, layout, and values.

Comment: If it contained all file you won't have got resource not found, my friend

Comment: After I unzip the .zip file, what do I select when I import a project into android studio?

Answer (score 0):

just open your project instead of importing it may it will help you.